# How to overcome Selenium CSS parent only CSS selector limitation

Tags: javascript, html, css, testing, selenium

Is there a known solution to do CSS selectors like this one in Selenium?

```
$('.sss').find('>div.ui-collapsible-content')
```

works fine on Chrome developer tools.

In Selnenium it throws exception

```
OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidElementStateException : invalid element state: Failed to execute    'querySelector' on 'Element': '>div.ui-collapsible-content' is not a valid selector.
(Session info: chrome=33.0.1750.154)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.8.241075,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86)
```

I could just use selector without parent part

```
.find('div.ui-collapsible-content')
```

and only take first element, but this is somewhat hacky solution and someone must have ran into similar situation by now and found more elegant solution than this.

jsfiddle HTML example - http://jsfiddle.net/uHYZL/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't call this a limitation. This looks like expected behaviour to me, as I don't see `>div.ui-collapsible-content` being a valid [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/) in the first place.

The reason `$('.sss').find('>div.ui-collapsible-content')` works is because you are using jQuery, which uses [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) as the CSS selecting engine under the hood. It supports things that W3C spec doesn't support, like `:contains()` etc.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Wouldn't something like below suit you needs?

```
var content = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".sss > div.ui-collapsible-content"));
```

Comment: I am working in a tree structure and all the children that have .ui-collapsible-content class are being selected too.

Comment: @LIUFA: (I don't use jQuery very often, but) I don't the see the difference between `$('.sss').find('>div.ui-collapsible-content')` and `".sss > div.ui-collapsible-content"`. Any demo available out there?

Comment: .sss is for example purposes only however solution to include element itself into selector works, just waiting for 10 min to accept answer. Thanks.

Comment: Just realised it doesn't :) I was selecting child element all this time, proposal to use IWebDriver.FindElement() against IWebElement.FindElements() including element itself would select multiple elements on the page, while including parent class would select only children. We are to tile one.

Comment: @LIUFA: A demo might be helpful. I used `$('#question-mini-list').find('>div.question-summary')` and `$$('#question-mini-list>div.question-summary')` for StackOverflow, looks the same to me.

Comment: @LIUFA: Still not sure what you are talking about. :(. Looks the same still. http://imgur.com/DNqE2TA

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51411/discussion-between-liufa-and-user1177636)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Xpath? It would look pretty horrible and complex but I am sure you could construct a selector which would only find parents, then continue from there.

i would try and construct one but don't have access to a computer currently